# How to add meta tags inside single image page?

Tags: wp-head

Hello im trying to add custom meta tags from facebook share button inside image.php file , and i dont know why they dont display, this is how my code looks:

```
        function add_facebook_image_code(){
            ?>

                <meta property="og:url"           content="http://www.example.com/<?=$post->post_name ?>/" />
                <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
                <meta property="og:title"         content="example.com - <?=$post->post_title ?>" />
                <meta property="og:image"         content="<?=$post->guid ?>" />

            <?php

        }

        add_action('wp_head', 'add_facebook_image_code');
```

I add this code inside image.php, is it possible to do it only inside that file ?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Ok i fix the problem, my code was inside loop (i know  it was stupid ) it should be on top of page before get_header();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because when the execution is hitting your code is already too late to hook on `wp_head`.

If you want to have your code in image.php, make sure you place it before `get_header()`.

In any case, I would move the code to functions.php or dedicated file and maybe use `is_attachment()` to conditionally print the meta tags.

Comment: Thanks i already fix it by myself , but you are right. It should be before get_header() not inside my code :)